# create a list item with a background color including list item number on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an ordered list with a background color on hover, problem is that i am not able to get the number to change color on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ap327u9/1/

i have tried using the list-item-position: inside but that puts the number above the content and not along side of it like a normal list

```
<div class="container">
  <ol>
  <li class="item-container">Help me get the background color to pink even the list number please.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  ol li:hover {
        background: pink;
  }
}
```

I want the the whole line including the number with text to change background color

Comment: _"i have tried using the list-item-position: inside but that puts the number above the content and not along side of it like a normal list"_ No it doesn't. It works. But if that's what you're seeing then you must have more CSS or code that's affecting the output. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 
if you checkout the jsfiddle, youll see that in fact it doesnt work.

Comment: You should probably check your work https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yefbxtq2/

Comment: @j08691 
sweet. Thanks :)

Comment: But wait, you said that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use list-style-position and not list-item-position

```
ol {
list-style-position: inside;
}
```